# Getaddrinfo - why send additional information?

Tags: winsock, winsock2

Can anyone please suggest, since it is not very clear from MSDN why it is necessary to fill in the following fields of the addrinfo structure to transfer this data along with a call to the Getaddinfo () function:

```
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; //or AF_INET ... AF_INET6
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
```

It's just that there are two incomprehensible moments to me:

-I can set all members of the addrinfo structure to zero and getaddrinfo exits without error and returns data.

-I can't understand why they need to be specified at all, because I just request information about the ip-address by domain name, and do not provide it to the DNS server.

The same applies to the second parameter of getaddrinfo - this is the service number (like http / https) or the port number (80/443) - if you nullify and pass them to Getaddinfo, it also works.
And here, too, I cannot understand why the DNS server needs this information?
Without this information, wouldn't DNS be able to find all the information it stores by domain name alone?

Comment: also nobody knows? :(

Comment: The additional fields are required to fill the returned addrinfo / sockaddr list. getaddrinfo is not just a address resolver. It allows you to build protocol independent applications.